Why does typescript allow a concrete class to implement an abstract with more specific parameter types
Consider the following:
type X = {
  a: number;
};
type Y = X & { b: number };

abstract class XX {
  abstract yy(x: X): void;
}

class YY implements XX {
  yy(x: Y): void {
    console.log(x.b);
  }
}

const xxs: XX[] = [new YY()];
xxs[0].yy({ a: 1 });

The code above compiles without errors, but why does TS allow a concrete class (YY) to implement an abstract method (yy) receiving a parameter of a narrower type (Y) of the type declared in the abstract class (X)?
This makes the method yy accept a X input without compiler errors though the signature and contents of the method clearly expects an Y.

Surely type X is narrower than type Y not the other way round? Since Y is wider than type X it should not be a problem to satisfy X if the function accepts Y

@slebetman Y is narrower: Every Y is X, but not every X is Y.

TS is intentionally unsound with method parameters this way. If you want the proper contravariant checking you need to switch to a function-valued property syntax as shown in this playground link. See the linked q/a above for more information.
